# Android: Change activity state when receiving a phone call

Tags: android, phone-call

A problem came up in my latest android programming project.
The problem is I would like to change Activity that launches when the phone receives a call.
Is it possible to add some text after the contact name when a call is received.
I have search the web for something that could do that, and been looking in the API for hours and I cannot find anything, is it possible with reflection of something like that?
I have made a class that listens to when the phone_state is receiving a call, and I can get the incomming number, but I would like to change the appearance on the screen.

// Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can,t edit InCallScreen interface. but you can display some Text or whatever above it using toast,

class MyToast ............

```
package i4nc4mp.myLock.phone;


/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */



import android.app.INotificationManager;
import android.app.ITransientNotification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.WindowManagerImpl;
    import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A toast is a view containing a quick little message for the user.  The toast class
 * helps you create and show those.
 * {@more}
 *
 * <p>
 * When the view is shown to the user, appears as a floating view over the
 * application.  It will never receive focus.  The user will probably be in the
 * middle of typing something else.  The idea is to be as unobtrusive as
 * possible, while still showing the user the information you want them to see.
 * Two examples are the volume control, and the brief message saying that your
 * settings have been saved.
 * <p>
 * The easiest way to use this class is to call one of the static methods that constructs
 * everything you need and returns a new Toast object.
 */ 
public class MyToast {
    static final String TAG = "Toast";
    static final boolean localLOGV = false;

    /**
     * Show the view or text notification for a short period of time.  This time
     * could be user-definable.  This is the default.
     * @see #setDuration
     */
    public static final int LENGTH_SHORT = 0;

    /**
     * Show the view or text notification for a long period of time.  This time
     * could be user-definable.
     * @see #setDuration
     */
    public static final int LENGTH_LONG = 1;

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();    
    final Context mContext;
    final TN mTN;
    int mDuration;
    int mGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
    int mX, mY;
    float mHorizontalMargin;
    float mVerticalMargin;
    View mView;
    View mNextView;

    /**
     * Construct an empty Toast object.  You must call {@link #setView} before you
     * can call {@link #show}.
     *
     * @param context  The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *                 or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     */
    public MyToast(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mTN = new TN();
        mY = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                com.android.internal.R.dimen.toast_y_offset);
    }

    /**
     * Show the view for the specified duration.
     */
    public void show() {
        if (mNextView == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("setView must have been called");
        }

        INotificationManager service = getService();

        String pkg = mContext.getPackageName();

        TN tn = mTN;

        try {

            service.enqueueToast(pkg, tn, mDuration);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet.
     * You do not normally have to call this.  Normally view will disappear on its own
     * after the appropriate duration.
     */
    public void cancel() {
        mTN.myHide();
        // TODO this still needs to cancel the inflight notification if any
    }

    /**
     * Set the view to show.
     * @see #getView
     */
    public void setView(View view) {
        mNextView = view;
    }

    /**
     * Return the view.
     * @see #setView
     */
    public View getView() {
        return mNextView;
    }

    /**
     * Set how long to show the view for.
     * @see #LENGTH_SHORT
     * @see #LENGTH_LONG
     */
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        mDuration = duration;
    }

    /**
     * Return the duration.
     * @see #setDuration
     */
    public int getDuration() {
        return mDuration;
    }

    /**
     * Set the margins of the view.
     *
     * @param horizontalMargin The horizontal margin, in percentage of the
     *        container width, between the container's edges and the
     *        notification
     * @param verticalMargin The vertical margin, in percentage of the
     *        container height, between the container's edges and the
     *        notification
     */
    public void setMargin(float horizontalMargin, float verticalMargin) {
        mHorizontalMargin = horizontalMargin;
        mVerticalMargin = verticalMargin;
    }

    /**
     * Return the horizontal margin.
     */
    public float getHorizontalMargin() {
        return mHorizontalMargin;
    }

    /**
     * Return the vertical margin.
     */
    public float getVerticalMargin() {
        return mVerticalMargin;
    }

    /**
     * Set the location at which the notification should appear on the screen.
     * @see android.view.Gravity
     * @see #getGravity
     */
    public void setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        mGravity = gravity;
        mX = xOffset;
        mY = yOffset;
    }

     /**
     * Get the location at which the notification should appear on the screen.
     * @see android.view.Gravity
     * @see #getGravity
     */
    public int getGravity() {
        return mGravity;
    }

    /**
     * Return the X offset in pixels to apply to the gravity's location.
     */
    public int getXOffset() {
        return mX;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Y offset in pixels to apply to the gravity's location.
     */
    public int getYOffset() {
        return mY;
    }

    /**
     * Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.
     *
     * @param context  The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *                 or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param text     The text to show.  Can be formatted text.
     * @param duration How long to display the message.  Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
     *                 {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
     *
     */
    public static MyToast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        MyToast result = new MyToast(context);

        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
        tv.setText(text);

        result.mNextView = v;
        result.mDuration = duration;

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Make a standard toast that just contains a text view with the text from a resource.
     *
     * @param context  The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *                 or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param resId    The resource id of the string resource to use.  Can be formatted text.
     * @param duration How long to display the message.  Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
     *                 {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
     *
     * @throws Resources.NotFoundException if the resource can't be found.
     */
    public static MyToast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
                                throws Resources.NotFoundException {
        return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration);
    }

    /**
     * Update the text in a Toast that was previously created using one of the makeText() methods.
     * @param resId The new text for the Toast.
     */
    public void setText(int resId) {
        setText(mContext.getText(resId));
    }

    /**
     * Update the text in a Toast that was previously created using one of the makeText() methods.
     * @param s The new text for the Toast.
     */
    public void setText(CharSequence s) {
        if (mNextView == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This Toast was not created with Toast.makeText()");
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) mNextView.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
        if (tv == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This Toast was not created with Toast.makeText()");
        }
        tv.setText(s);
    }

    // =======================================================================================
    // All the gunk below is the interaction with the Notification Service, which handles
    // the proper ordering of these system-wide.
    // =======================================================================================

    private static INotificationManager sService;

    static private INotificationManager getService() {
        if (sService != null) {
            return sService;
        }
        sService = INotificationManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("notification"));
        return sService;
    }

    private class TN extends ITransientNotification.Stub {
        final Runnable mShow = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                handleShow();
            }
        };

        final Runnable mHide = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                handleHide();
            }
        };

        private final WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        WindowManagerImpl mWM;

        TN() {
            // XXX This should be changed to use a Dialog, with a Theme.Toast
            // defined that sets up the layout params appropriately.
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mParams;
            params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
            params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
            params.windowAnimations = com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert;
            params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
            params.setTitle("Toast");
        }

        /**
         * schedule handleShow into the right thread
         */
        public void show() {
            if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "SHOW: " + this);
            mHandler.post(mShow);
        }

        /**
         * schedule handleHide into the right thread
         */
        public void hide() {
            System.out.println("hide called");
            if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "HIDE: " + this);
           // mHandler.post(mHide);
        }
        public void myHide(){
            System.out.println("my hide called");
            if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "HIDE: " + this);
           mHandler.post(mHide);
        }
        public void handleShow() {
            if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "HANDLE SHOW: " + this + " mView=" + mView
                    + " mNextView=" + mNextView);
            if (mView != mNextView) {
                // remove the old view if necessary
                handleHide();
                mView = mNextView;
                mWM = WindowManagerImpl.getDefault();
                final int gravity = mGravity;
                mParams.gravity = gravity;
                if ((gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL) {
                    mParams.horizontalWeight = 1.0f;
                }
                if ((gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL) {
                    mParams.verticalWeight = 1.0f;
                }
                mParams.x = mX;
                mParams.y = mY;
                mParams.verticalMargin = mVerticalMargin;
                mParams.horizontalMargin = mHorizontalMargin;
                if (mView.getParent() != null) {
                    if (localLOGV) Log.v(
                            TAG, "REMOVE! " + mView + " in " + this);
                    mWM.removeView(mView);
                }
                if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "ADD! " + mView + " in " + this);
                mWM.addView(mView, mParams);
            }
        }

        public void handleHide() {
            //System.out.println("handle hid ecalles");
            if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "HANDLE HIDE: " + this + " mView=" + mView);
            if (mView != null) {
                // note: checking parent() just to make sure the view has
                // been added...  i have seen cases where we get here when
                // the view isn't yet added, so let's try not to crash.
                if (mView.getParent() != null) {
                    if (localLOGV) Log.v(
                            TAG, "REMOVE! " + mView + " in " + this);
                    mWM.removeView(mView);
                }

                mView = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// in broadcaste receiver ..........

```
 String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
toast = new MyToast(context);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.setView(view);  
 toast.show();
  }
 else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
 toast.cancel();
  }
else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
toast.cancel();

}
}
```

Comment: if that is the case then how is the following link shows customised incoming call screen ?

Comment: if you know any link then why you are not answering the question?

Comment: Sorry for missing out the link http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/phonecalls.html